# How to recursively join lists in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which contains lists, like this:

```
l = ['celery', 'beef', ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']]
```

And I want to join them with different characters depending on whether they are in the list or a list-within-a-list, i.e. to get this output:

```
celery\tbeef\tapples\noranges\nbananas
```

Where the top-level items are joined with tabs, and the second-level items are joined with newlines.

I tried `joined = "\t".join(l)` but this gives a TypeError, and I was hoping `joined = '\t'.join('\n'.join(l))` would work, but it doesn't. I also tried:

```
clean=""
for line in output: 
    if isinstance(line, list): 
        line = '\n'.join(line) #separate multiple-line outputs with newlines
    clean += line 

clean = '\t'.join(output)
```

Answer (score 6):

You were so close:

```
clean = []
for line in output: 
    if isinstance(line, list): 
        line = '\n'.join(line) #separate multiple-line outputs with newlines
    clean.append(line)

clean = '\t'.join(clean)
```

or use a list comprehension:

```
'\t'.join(['\n'.join(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in output])
```

Demo of the one-liner:

```
>>> output = ['celery', 'beef', ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']] 
>>> '\t'.join(['\n'.join(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in output])
'celery\tbeef\tapples\noranges\nbananas'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line by using lambda recursively:

```py
l = ['celery', 'beef', ['apples', 'oranges', ['bananas', 'house']]] 

f = lambda L: '\t'.join([f(x) if type(x) is list else x for x in L])
f(l)
```

output:

```
'celery\tbeef\tapples\toranges\tbananas\thouse'
```